# Fill in missing days with previous or neighbouring value

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to come up with SQL script that fills in missing dates

- for each combination of NAME_ and PARAM_
- For PARAM_ = ABOVE, sets missing value to last known value of PARAM_ = ABOVE
- For PARAM_ = NEXT, sets missing value to current date's value of PARAM_ = ABOVE
- Assumes value NULL if no initial PARAM_ = ABOVE
- Convert input NULL to 0

**Input**

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (NAME_, DATE_, PARAM_, VALUE) AS
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-26', 'ABOV', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-26', 'NEXT', 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-27', 'NEXT', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-28', 'NEXT', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL

  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-25', 'NEXT', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-28', 'ABOV', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-28', 'NEXT', 4 FROM DUAL;
```

**Output**

```
CREATE TABLE table_name2 (NAME_, DATE_, PARAM_, VALUE) AS
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-26', 'ABOV', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-26', 'NEXT', 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-27', 'ABOV', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-27', 'NEXT', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-28', 'ABOV', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-28', 'NEXT', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-29', 'ABOV', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-29', 'NEXT', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL

  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-25', 'ABOV', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-25', 'NEXT', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-26', 'ABOV', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-26', 'NEXT', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-27', 'ABOV', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-27', 'NEXT', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-28', 'ABOV', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-28', 'NEXT', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-29', 'ABOV', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-29', 'NEXT', 0 FROM DUAL;
```

**Attempt**

```
SELECT
  t.NAME_,
  t.DATE_,
  t.PARAM_,
  LAST_VALUE(VALUE_) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
    PARTITION BY t.NAME_, t.PARAM_ ORDER BY d.DATE_) AS VALUE_

FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT DATE_ FROM table_name) d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT NAME_, DATE_, PARAM_, COALESCE(VALUE, 0) as VALUE_  
    FROM table_name
    WHERE PARAM_ in ('ABOV', 'NEXT')) t

PARTITION BY
    (NAME_, PARAM_) ON (t.DATE_ = d.DATE_)

ORDER BY
    NAME_, PARAM_, DATE_
```

I cannot quite get it working:

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ehh_YB9w)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the sample question in the question (not just the fiddle, so the question is self contained); the expected output for that sample data; and an explanation (simple English, not code) of the logic used to reach the expected output from that sample data. At the moment the question is not clear what you want the expected output to be and the pseudo-code explanation is difficult to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN` to generate all combinations of `date_` and `param_` for each `name_` and then use a `MODEL` clause to generate successive values based on the previous values:

```sql
SELECT name_, date_, param_, value
FROM   (
  SELECT t.name_,
         d.date_,
         p.param_,
         COALESCE(
           t.value,
           CASE WHEN t.date_ IS NOT NULL AND t.param_ IS NOT NULL THEN 0 END
         ) AS value,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.name_ ORDER BY d.date_, p.param_) AS rn
  FROM   (SELECT 'ABOV' AS param_ FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 'NEXT' FROM DUAL) p
         CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT DISTINCT date_ FROM table_name) d
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
         PARTITION BY (t.name_)
         ON (   p.param_ = t.param_
            AND d.date_  = t.date_)
)
MODEL
  PARTITION BY (name_)
  DIMENSION BY (rn)
  MEASURES (date_, param_, value)  
  RULES (
    value[rn>1] = COALESCE(
                    value[cv()],
                    CASE param_[cv()]
                    WHEN 'ABOV'
                    THEN value[cv() - 2]
                    ELSE value[cv() - 1]
                    END
                  )
  )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (NAME_, DATE_, PARAM_, VALUE) AS
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-26', 'ABOV', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-26', 'NEXT', 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-27', 'NEXT', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-28', 'NEXT', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL

  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-25', 'NEXT', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-28', 'ABOV', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-28', 'NEXT', 4 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| NAME_ | DATE_ | PARAM_ | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | ABOV | *null* |
| A | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | NEXT | *null* |
| A | 2023-09-26 00:00:00 | ABOV | 0 |
| A | 2023-09-26 00:00:00 | NEXT | 11 |
| A | 2023-09-27 00:00:00 | ABOV | 0 |
| A | 2023-09-27 00:00:00 | NEXT | 10 |
| A | 2023-09-28 00:00:00 | ABOV | 0 |
| A | 2023-09-28 00:00:00 | NEXT | 12 |
| B | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | ABOV | *null* |
| B | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | NEXT | 2 |
| B | 2023-09-26 00:00:00 | ABOV | *null* |
| B | 2023-09-26 00:00:00 | NEXT | *null* |
| B | 2023-09-27 00:00:00 | ABOV | *null* |
| B | 2023-09-27 00:00:00 | NEXT | *null* |
| B | 2023-09-28 00:00:00 | ABOV | 0 |
| B | 2023-09-28 00:00:00 | NEXT | 4 |

---

If you only want the date ranges from the minimum to the maximum `date_` for each `name_` then:

```sql
WITH dates (name_, date_, end_date) AS (
  SELECT name_, MIN(date_), MAX(date_)
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY name_
UNION ALL
  SELECT name_, date_ + 1, end_date
  FROM   dates
  WHERE  date_ + 1 <= end_date
),
params (param_) AS (
  SELECT 'ABOV' AS param_ FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NEXT' FROM DUAL
),
combined (name_, date_, param_, value, rn) AS (
  SELECT d.name_,
         d.date_,
         p.param_,
         COALESCE(
           t.value,
           CASE WHEN t.date_ IS NOT NULL AND t.param_ IS NOT NULL THEN 0 END
         ) AS value,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.name_ ORDER BY d.date_, p.param_) AS rn
  FROM   params p
         CROSS JOIN dates d
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
         ON (   p.param_ = t.param_
            AND d.name_  = t.name_
            AND d.date_  = t.date_ )
)
SELECT name_, date_, param_, value
FROM   combined
MODEL
  PARTITION BY (name_)
  DIMENSION BY (rn)
  MEASURES (date_, param_, value)  
  RULES (
    value[rn>1] = COALESCE(
                    value[cv()],
                    CASE param_[cv()]
                    WHEN 'ABOV'
                    THEN value[cv() - 2]
                    ELSE value[cv() - 1]
                    END
                  )
  )
```

Which outputs:

| NAME_ | DATE_ | PARAM_ | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-09-26 00:00:00 | ABOV | 0 |
| A | 2023-09-26 00:00:00 | NEXT | 11 |
| A | 2023-09-27 00:00:00 | ABOV | 0 |
| A | 2023-09-27 00:00:00 | NEXT | 10 |
| A | 2023-09-28 00:00:00 | ABOV | 0 |
| A | 2023-09-28 00:00:00 | NEXT | 12 |
| B | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | ABOV | *null* |
| B | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | NEXT | 2 |
| B | 2023-09-26 00:00:00 | ABOV | *null* |
| B | 2023-09-26 00:00:00 | NEXT | *null* |
| B | 2023-09-27 00:00:00 | ABOV | *null* |
| B | 2023-09-27 00:00:00 | NEXT | *null* |
| B | 2023-09-28 00:00:00 | ABOV | 0 |
| B | 2023-09-28 00:00:00 | NEXT | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oFRcXAyZ)